# Gap Analysis/Report for CSV in Python 3.6.2

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

```
Start         End
MM0001        MM0009
MM0010        MM0020
MM0030        MM0039
MM0059        MM0071
```

Good afternoon, I wanted to create code in Python in 3.6.2 that will allow me to essentially look for gaps in rows of consecutive numbers, such as with this one. It would then output to the screen for the missing numbers in a format similar to below:

```
MM0021    MM0029
MM0040    MM0051
MM0052    MM0058
```

I've created some code for this program based on an answer I found around here, but I don't believe it's complete, as well as it being done in Python 2.7 I believe. I however used it as a basis for what I was trying to do.

```
import csv
with open('thedata.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader (csvfile)
    for line, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
    if not row:
       print 'Start of line', line, 'Contents', row
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would help, but I’m not sure what your csv looks like. Could you post the first couple lines or something?

Comment: 1 through 9 is first line, 10- 20 is second, 30-39 is third, 59-71 is fourth. Header is simply Start for first row, End for Second. Sorry, don't know how to indent like code in comment box!

Comment: The CSV is the first code indent in the topic, if that makes it easier for you.

Comment: In your sample “fixed” output, did you mean to put ```MM0030``` rather than ```MM00040```?

Comment: It's 30. I have to find the missing rows of data within the CSV. And export them to the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

def out(*args): 
    print('{},{}'.format(*(str(i).rjust(4, "0") for i in args)))

prev = 0
data = csv.reader(open('thedata.csv'))

print(*next(data), sep=', ') #  header

for line in data:
    start, end = (int(s.strip()[2:]) for s in line)

    if start != prev+1:
        out(prev+1, start-1)

    prev = end
    out(start, end)
```

it’s really ugly sorry, but should work?

outputs comma separated text

if something doesn’t work, or you want it to save to a file, just comment

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It doesn't have any errors, but the program itself isn't starting in the 3.6.2 module either as well. If you have any ideas, I'm open to hearing you out! And again, thank you!

Comment: Now it says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GapReport.py", line 14, in <module>
    start, end = (int(c.strip()[2:]) for c in line)
  File "GapReport.py", line 14, in <genexpr>
    start, end = (int(c.strip()[2:]) for c in line)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AC-SEC 000000001'

Comment: okay, I assumed every line in your file was of the format ```MM1234```. It seems like there was a line with a format ```AC-SEC 000000001```.